# CancellationTokenSource proper replace with new one

Tags: c#, task, token, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

The `Window` hides automatically after 5 seconds after it appears (`ShowWindow` method). It can be also hide manually (`HideWindow` method). Here is my current implementation.

**The issue:** When I open and then close window manually some times in row, it then hides immediately to 1 sec after opening. It shouldn't by design. The reason is I replace CTS with new one, and cancellation is never requested. I have poor skill with CTS and can't get in mind how to implement this properly.

```
public class Window
    {
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        public CancellationTokenSource HideErrorWindowCTS { get; set; }

        public async void ShowWindow()
        {
            Visible = true;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            if (!HideErrorWindowCTS.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Visible = false;
            }
        }

        public void HideWindow()
        {
            HideErrorWindowCTS.Cancel();
            HideErrorWindowCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should pass the _token_ to the method rather than the token source - then you can use [`CancellationToken.None`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none(v=vs.110).aspx) when you don't want it to cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ShowWindow` looks at `HideErrorWindowCTS`, it's looking at the *newly updated* cancellation token source, not the token corresponding to the CTS at the time you showed the window.  Just grab ahold of that token and store it in a local variable *before* you wait, so that even if `HideErrorWindowCTS` changes, you still have the same token to check after the delay has finished.